# Prometheus error starting web server: address already in use

Tags: prometheus

Need help, after starting Prometheus I get below error running in CentOS:

```
msg="Error starting web server, exiting gracefully" err="listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9090: bind: address already in use"
level=info ts=2017-11-29T07:16:05.523067725Z caller=main.go:384 msg="See you next time!"
level=info ts=2017-11-29T07:16:05.523216386Z caller=targetmanager.go:87 component="target manager" msg="Stopping target manager..."
level=info ts=2017-11-29T07:16:05.523247638Z caller=targetmanager.go:99 component="target manager" msg="Target manager stopped"
level=info ts=2017-11-29T07:16:05.523257989Z caller=manager.go:455 component="rule manager" msg="Stopping rule manager..."
level=info ts=2017-11-29T07:16:05.52326427Z caller=manager.go:461 component="rule manager" msg="Rule manager stopped"
level=info ts=2017-11-29T07:16:05.523271345Z caller=notifier.go:483 component=notifier msg="Stopping notification handler..."
```

Answer (score 9):

You can change the port Prometheus uses like this (port 9010 in this case):

```
./prometheus --web.listen-address=:9010 &
```

Answer (score 4):

The port 9090 is already in use by another program.

You need to find the process id (pid) of whatever is running on that port and kill it.

you can use `lsof -i :9090` to get the pid and then use `sudo kill -9 <pid>` to kill the program and free up the port so you can run Prometheus.

Comment: i used same cmd but below one process is not able to kill getting regularly,root@ibm-ms prometheus-2.0.0.linux-amd64]# lsof -i :9090
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd   1 root   27u  IPv6  14152      0t0  TCP *:websm (LISTEN)
[root@ibm-ms prometheus-2.0.0.linux-amd64]# sudo kill -9 1
[root@ibm-ms prometheus-2.0.0.linux-amd64]# lsof -i :9090
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd   1 root   27u  IPv6  14152      0t0  TCP *:websm (LISTEN)
[root@ibm-ms prometheus-2.0.0.linux-amd64]#

Comment: after  using kill cmd:[root@ibm-ms prometheus-2.0.0.linux-amd64]# sudo kill -9 1
[root@ibm-ms prometheus-2.0.0.linux-amd64]# lsof -i :9090
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd   1 root   27u  IPv6  14152      0t0  TCP *:websm (LISTEN)

Comment: Strangely, the offending process is prometheus, and when killing said process it immediately pops up under a new PID again - what could be causing this?